# to throw a mean one

Tags: meaning

I have heard the following dialogue in the movie Focus:

> Jess: Nick told me about the thing with his father.
>
> Farhad: He told you that? I have heard it from other people, but he has never told me. You must throw a mean one!

What does "to throw a mean one" mean in this context? I think it's an informal expression which means "to be good at sex", but I'm not sure.

Comment: the slang expression ***throw a mean one*** derives from ***throw a [good, effective] punch***, as in boxing. It's got no real currency, but apparently in the specific cited context we can reasonably understand it as meaning *You'#re really good at what you do!* (being *such* a good hooker / "good screw" that clients / sexual partners forget themselves and divulge secrets).

Answer (score 1):

When I watched the movie, I just accepted that line as some sort of slangy sexual compliment I didn’t understand.

Since you asked, though, I’ve recalled that “throw” is hooker slang for sex. Also, “mean” can sometimes be used to mean very good/strong (like a “that pitcher has a mean fastball”). So, I would guess Farhad is comparing Jess employing her sexual skills to extract personal secrets from Nicky to a hooker using those same skills to extract money. That could easily be meant as a compliment between two con artists.

Or I could be totally off base here. It’s not a common phrase.